# Conditional averages (AVERAGEIF, AVERAGEIFS, or other option?)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Perhaps it's just been a long week, but I can't think of how to get a pretty simple average.

Here's my data (two columns):

```
1/3/1994        1165
1/4/1994        1162
1/5/1994        1133
1/6/1994        1133
1/7/1994        1138
1/10/1994       1143
1/11/1994       1118
1/12/1994       1150
1/13/1994       1171
1/14/1994       1177
1/17/1994       1161
1/18/1994       1162
1/19/1994       1121
1/20/1994       1112
1/21/1994       1129
1/24/1994       1136
1/25/1994       1124
1/26/1994       1118
1/27/1994       1127
1/28/1994       1133
1/31/1994       1088
2/1/1994        1055
2/2/1994        1051
2/3/1994        1071
2/4/1994        1079
2/7/1994        1054
2/8/1994        1079
2/9/1994        1079
2/10/1994       1089
2/11/1994       1074
2/14/1994       1083
2/15/1994       1068
2/16/1994       1075
2/17/1994       1071
```

As you can see, it's a column of dates (that continue until Sept. 9 2015, so it's long), and another of price.  I am just trying to get the averages for January each month, of each year (i.e. Jan 1994, 1995, 1996 ... 2015, then Feb 1994, etc).

Here's the table I plan on using the formula in:

```
             2007   2008    2009    2010    2011
January                 
February                    
March                   
April
```

So, in the cell right of "January" and below "2007", I want the average of prices that are in Jan, 2007.

I tried using this (again, my data starts in A1 and B1):

`=AverageIfs(B:B,year(A:A),1994,month(A:A),1)` (regular and as array), but it doesn't work - I keep getting the error "The formula you typed contains an error."  (I'd really prefer this to be a formula, rather than a VB solution)

Thanks for any ideas!

Edit: In the mean time, I have created two helper columns, that are just the `Month()` and `Year()` of each row of data.  Then I can use `=AverageIfs(B:B,[month helper range],1,[year helper range],2007)`.  Is there a way to do this without a helper column though?

Comment: Have you looked into Pivot Tables ?  A Pivot table should do this for you with just a couple clips .. no formulas ;)

Comment: @Ditto - good idea, I'll look in to that.  However, I'm also just trying to figure out how to do this from a formula standpoint (I'm trying to get better with formulas so I don't need to rely of VB so much).

Comment: Consider changing the title of the question so people who are looking for conditional averages can find this even if they're not searching for `AVERAGEIF` or their conditions are not based on dates.

Comment: @andrew.cuthbert - good thinking, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
=AVERAGE(IF(YEAR(A:A)=1994,IF(MONTH(A:A)=1,B:B,""),""))
```

entered as an array formula (CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER). If you want to use the month as text you could use

```
=AVERAGE(IF(YEAR(A:A)=1994,IF(TEXT(A:A,"mmmm")="January",B:B,""),""))
```

Hope that helps

Comment: That's awesome - uses `Average` and everything.  Does yours work, where mine didn't, because you're wrapping the `if` statements inside the `average`, instead of using `averageif`? (Also, thanks because it's interesting that I can't do this with `AverageIf`, but I can with `Average(if(`)

Comment: I haven't used AVERAGEIF, SUMIF, etc. to much because when they were first introduced it seemed like only simple criteria could be used. I think there's more flexibility now, but I haven't added them to my toolbox. With nested IFs inside of AVERAGE (or SUM, STDEV, etc.) you can cascade as many filters on your data as you like. Excel's statistical functions skip text values so you have IF return "" (or "BAD" or whatever) on any data you want to exclude.

Comment: Agree with @xidgel, these functions are severely limited because they only allow you to use the actual values in the condition range, rather than allowing you to apply transformations to those values. I wish you could do something like this: `=AVERAGEIFS(B:B,MONTH(A:A),1,YEAR(A:A),1994)`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the most concise solution, but it works. You can use `SUMPRODUCT` as follows:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($A:$A)=1)*(YEAR($A:$A)=1994)*$B:$B)/SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($A:$A)=1)*(YEAR($A:$A)=1994))
```

What this is essentially doing is summing the values in column B based on the two criteria, and then counting the number of rows that matched the criteria and dividing by that number.

For each row, the `MONTH` and `YEAR` conditions evaluate to either 1 (true) or 0 (false) and then those two values are multiplied with the value in column B, resulting in column B's value if both conditions are true, or 0 if one or both conditions are false.

Comment: Holy cow - that works!  I must admit that `Sumproduct` is just about the one formula that still intimidates and confuses me :P  I'm going to have to take time to think through this one.  Do you not think it's possible with some kind of `Averageif()`? (I don't think so anymore, after looking at the data and without helper columns).  Thanks a ton!

Comment: I don't think so either without helper columns, but I'm definitely not sure about that. I'm rather out of practice with Excel at the moment. I was pretty mystified the first time I learned about using `SUMPRODUCT` this way as well, but it's worth learning because it's a really powerful tool.

Comment: @Xidgel posted an answer with `Average(if(` which seems to work over `AverageIf()` which is interesting. (Changed answer to his, just because I was looking for an answer with Average, but thanks a lot for your `sumproduct`, it's a great help to my understanding!)

Answer (score 1):

- assuming your data has a header: "Date" and "Price" in cells A1, B1.
- assuming your data begins in `A2 = "1/3/1994"` and `B2 = 1165`

`C1 = "Month"
D1 = "Year"
C2 = =TEXT(A2,"Mmmm")
D2 = =YEAR(A2)`

Copy Cells C2+D2 down ...

I place your new table in:

`H2 = "January"
H3 = "February"`

... etc.

`I1 = 1994
J1 = 1995`

... etc.

`I2 = =AVERAGEIFS($B:$B,$C:$C,$H2,$D:$D,I$1)`

and copy that formula throughout the table.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! That's what I did before the answers without helper columns were posted.  This certainly works, I just was looking for something without helper columns (again, less for practical reasons and more for learning formulas better).

Comment: ahh, I was leaving those in so you can "learn" ;)  lol .. there's a couple other solutions posted which are similar, minus the helper columns, see if those help then ..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use AVERAGEIFS() and you should. This is about a thousand times faster than the accepted answer:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&DATE(1994,1,1),A:A,"<"&DATE(1994,2,1))
```

You can even do it this way for a more concise formula, but I believe it raises problems for non-USA users because of their date format settings:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A,">=1/1/94",A:A,"<2/1/94")
```

Comment: @BruceWayne I always love reading  your comments. Please give me one.

Comment: Excel Hero is correct about calculation speed --- AVERAGEIFS is much faster. It seems like it will need to be modified slightly to handle December.

Answer (score 0):

This solution requires to use in the *"table with the results"* the number of the month instead of the names of the month

It also assumes that the "table with the results" starts at `F2` (see picture)

Then use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS($B:$B,$A:$A,">="&DATE(G$2,$F3,1),$A:$A,"<="&EOMONTH(DATE(Q$19,$P20,1),0)),"N/A")
```

[image]

The formula shows `“N/A”` if there are no prices for the period (Year/Month), if you want to see blank then replace it with `“”`

*Small changes done to your sample data to work with several periods*